# Calling base class functions in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class c2
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C2");
        }//print
    }//c2

    public class c1 : c2
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C1");
        }//print
    }//c1
```

How do i call Print() of base class(c2) using derived class Object(Function name are same in both classes)

Comment: Why are you hiding a base class function. Are you sure you don't want to override it? The only use for hiding I ever had was to improve the parameter/return types while keeping the functionality the same.

Comment: If you don't override, you should also consider putting `new` in front of your method in class c1

Answer (score 5):

You can call it using `base.Print()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of `c1`, you can cast it to `c2` to be able to call that method.  For example:

```
var myc1 = new c1();

((c2)myc1).Print();
```

**NOTE:**  This solution works in this example because c1.Print() only **hides** c2.Print() as opposed to overriding it.

Comment: This of course only works because the base function was hidden and not overridden. M4N's suggestion works even with overridden functions.

Comment: Good point, I'll clarify that limitation in my answer.  My solution would be used if you have an instance of the class and want to call a particular implementation of that method.  When you are outside the class, the `base` keyword isn't going to work.

Comment: @CodeInChaos only for the immediate subclass, though

Answer (score 0):

```
public class c2 
{ 
    virtual public void Print() 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("C2"); 
    }//print 
}//c2 

public class c1 : c2 
{ 
    override public void Print() 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("C1"); 
        base.Print();
    }//print 
}//c1
```

if you want run at C1's Print C2'S function, too. But to override the function the print function
you shall declared it abstract or virtual.